# Mystic "gap" between a simulated cloth object and a collision object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I have this scene:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The pillow is with Cloth physics (pressure=5), and the ball is with Collision (not a rigid body).

But when I start the simulation, it ends up with:

[image: ![enter image description here]

As you can see there is a gap between the ball and the pillow. Where did it come from? The ball is not a Rigid Body, so there isn't sensitive margin.

If I make the ball a Rigid Body, it will simply clip through the pillow:

[image]

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you, it works!

Comment: Hey, no problem. Turns out I've been using a very old way of making pillows for quite some time. Your way works in 5 seconds. Thanks for "enlightening" my old ways ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your collision settings, make sure *Thickness Outer* is set to 0:

[image: Thickness]