# Cloth simulation keeps jittering and flying away

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I'm working on a simple scene where I've got a table set to a collision object and a plane strip of with a couple of subdivisions (previously a much larger plane) set to a cloth simulation I then let fall on the table, to fake a table cloth, but *every* single time I run the simulation it keeps jittering, intersecting with the table, colliding with some sort of margin (so not actually touching the table) and, worse of all, flies off after a coupe of seconds, as shown in the attached GIF.

[image]

I've tried changing the cloth's *Quality Steps* and cloth preset, enabled *Self Collision* but the issue still persists. Has anyone figured a good way to fix these issues?

(Any suggestions welcome !)

Blender file can be found here: [image]

EDIT 1:

I've tried Chris' suggested Self-collision settings and that seems to fix the jitters and flying away of the plane, but there's still a gap/margin once the plane collides with the table as shown below:
[image]
[image]

Updated blend file: [image]

EDIT 2

Chris' suggestion of going into the Cloths settings > Object Collision > and setting the Distance to ~0.002m seems to reduce the margin significantly, see comparison below:

[image]

EDIT 3

Though this thread was kinda resolved, I recently bumped into the issue again, and found out from [another thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228698/mystic-gap-between-a-simulated-cloth-object-and-a-collision-object) how to reduce the gap even further, the *Thickness Outer* setting in the collision object needs to be set to 0 (or closest to 0):

[image]

Comment: you could search for questions here on SE...there were a lot of similar questions. Or provide your blend file.

Comment: Hey Chris , I'm currently looking through some of the suggestions but haven't found a good fix yet, and I've just updated the post with the blend file, so feel free to let me know what could help in fixing it 

Comment: Increase the poly count of the cloth quite significantly

Comment: @James: nope, that won't help - maybe you should first TEST your proposals if you are not sure.

Comment: As Chris says, lower down the Self Collisions Distance value, also maybe increase the Collisions Quality value

Comment: Thank you both for helping me out on this! I've applied Chris' settings, which seem to fix the jitters and flying away, but still left with that weird gap/margin on the collision, any thoughts on why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: for the margin issue:

change object collision distance like so, quality to 8 and you get (maybe increase subdivisions of plane a bit):

[image]

---

go into your physics properties and turn down your distance like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for downloading the file @Chris and testing out the fix Chris!
I've created a new plane and gave it the self collision settings from your screenshot and while that fixes the jitters and the flying off, there's still an issue with the gap/margin with the collision object (the table), does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of that margin? or upload for update blend file?

Comment: Sure things! I've now added the screenshots and updated blend file. Thanks in advance 

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, just finished from work and tried out your fix. I went into the Cloth's *Collisions* settings and reduce the distance to 0.002 which seems to reduce it significantly (though not 100% fully). And also noticed that once I scale up the plane/cloth, the jitters for some reason reappear on collision.
Though your fix alone allows me to move forward, so thank you massively for helping me with this.

Comment: You are welcome. So if it helped you, please check the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It definitely did (just ✔), you're golden Chris, thank you so much. Gonna be jumping back into this early tomorrow and test out your suggestions in more scenarios 

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate that!!!